# How to preview cv::mat as an image in IOS project in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, imshow, opencv-mat

I am using opencv to process frames in a IOS project in Xcode (objectivec and c++). In the debugger mode, I want to see the cv::mat in the c++ method.  Since the "namedWindow", "imshow" cannot be used in IOS project, are there any methods to let me preview the cv::mat as an image in the debugger mode?

Thanks.

Comment: No,you have not preview cv::mat image in debuger mode.if you have to show cv::mat, then convert into uiimage and show in debuger mode.